# File Names Stored in an array and need to iterate through array creating a new file based on the name stored in each cell in C

Tags: c, file

I have 80+ text files which I am current'y reading into the program using `dirent.h`. This is placing them in an array, I am throwing them each through an algorithm which will compare the contents of each file to the other contents within that file and provide me with a percentage of how identical things within the file are. While doing that it will store the name of the file in `ArrayName[i]` and the percentage in `ArrayPercent[i]`.

I am pretty sure I know how to print those array values to a file, that is not the problem, the problem is using a variable as the filename. My current thoughts are something along the lines of

```
fprintf(**DIRECTORY HERE**,"%s %d", ArrayPercent[i], ArrayName[i][]);
```

The first time through a loop `ArrayName[0]` needs to go in DIRECTORY HERE as the filename.txt and the second time through `ArrayName[1]` needs to go there as *filename1.txt* for argument sake and so forth for the remainder of `ArrayName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple filename0.txt, filename1.txt, etc using:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    char buf[32];
    sprintf(buf, "filename%d_%s_%d", i, ArrayName[i], ArrayPercentage[i]);
}
```

Comment: use `snprintf` instead to avoid buffer overrun